# File.SetAttributes() not working on USB key as expected

Tags: c#, usb, fat, file-attributes

```
FileAttributes attrs = File.GetAttributes( path);
File.SetAttributes( path, FileAttributes.Hidden );
attrs = File.GetAttributes( path);
```

This code snippet works on my NTFS file system (C:\Temp...\whatever_file).  But when I try to perform this same operation on a USB key (FAT file system) it never successfully sets the Hidden attribute.  If I manually set it in Windows Explorer, then the first line returns correctly that it is set.  But the third line (checking it) never sets it if its not set.

I'll give a free puppy to whoever can tell me why. :)

UPDATE: When I say it doesn't work, I mean when I go back to Windows Explorer and look at the file it doesn't have the hidden attribute set.  In fact, when I do the second GetAttributes it shows that the bit is set.  But in Windows Explorer it is not set.  Even if I remove the USB key and reinsert it to be sure it refreshes correctly.

Comment: As much as I would like a puppy, I am not able to reproduce that, even on the FAT file system. The `SetAttributes` works as expected (I used your code verbatim). Try a different USB key?

Comment: I just did when I saw your first comment.  Same result.  SetAttributes fails on my USB key.  *sigh*

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your problem, sorry

Comment: where you are creating the Handle.. are you closing the filehandle...?? is there more code above the 3 lines that you are not displaying that would lead me to my question...?

Comment: Even with your update I can't reproduce it. When I run the code, then right click the file and hit properties, the "Hidden" checkbox becomes checked. What does `attrib filepath` print after you run the code?

Comment: Could windows be caching the file information on the USB drive?  If you remove the drive and plug it back in...is the flag set?

Comment: All boxen are unchecked.  If I use the properties dialog in Windows explorer to set/unset the attributes they are persisted.  But I can't do it programatically.  As I said above, even unplugging and reinserting the USB key to make sure its refreshed correctly doesn't work.

Comment: is that the only 3 lines you are using in the code when setting this.. ??

Comment: Can you list all the attributes that show up when you debug the code..?

Comment: Can you add a full (minimal) program listing that always reproduces the problem on your end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your input, but I completely neglected to look at the REST of my code where I recursively turn off the read-only attribute on all of the files I've written to my USB key, thus negating whatever I'd done before.

I repent in dust and ashes.